# Couldn't catch DataIntegrityViolationException with Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Trying to handle DataIntegrityViolationException with ControllerAdvice and return a custom response with Spring Boot v 1.3.3 & Spring Data REST v 2.4.4. Here are my classes:

**ExceptionControllerAdvice.java**

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
@ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
public ViolationResponse handleConflictException(DataIntegrityViolationException ex) throws Exception {
    return new ViolationResponse(ex.getMessage());
}
```

**ViolationResponse.java**

```
public class ViolationResponse {

private String message;

public ViolationResponse(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
}
```

I expect this to return 409 Conflict HTTP status code with message

> {"message" : "..."}

But I got 404 status with this response instead:

> {
>   "timestamp": 1463382639043
>   "status": 404
>   "error": "Not Found"
>   "exception": "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException"
>   "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [email_exists_constraint]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"
>   "path": "/api/v1/register"
>   }

What am I missing here? How to achieve the desired result?

**EDIT:**

**AuthController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class AuthController {
...
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public User register(@Valid @RequestBody User user, BindingResult result) throws ValidationException {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        throw new ValidationException(result.getAllErrors());
    }
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Comment: Show us the class declaration of Controller and the method signature  responsible for handling `/api/v1/register` please.

Comment: Hmmm, is the `ExceptionControllerAdvice` marked with `@ControllerAdvice` and created on application startup?

Comment: @miensol Yes, `ExceptionControllerAdvice` is annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` and is working as expected with another method I use there. The application even executes code inside `handleConflictException` method what can be seen during debugging. But instead of expected response, I get Spring Boot default response.

Comment: check out the accepted answer at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052092/constraintviolationexception-in-spring-rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate your method handleConflictException in ExceptionControllerAdvice.java with @ResponseBody. This will tell spring to make a JSON from your return object. @RestController has @ResponseBody inside, @ControllerAdvice do not.