# How catch hibernate/jpa constraint violations in Spring Boot?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have been unable to catch ConstraintViolationException (or DataIntegrityViolationException) in 
ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.
I would like to return the jpa failure (e.g. which constraint violated) in the response. 
(I prefer not to use @Valid on the method parameter and catch handleMethodArgumentNotValid).

```
...
import org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException;
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;

@ControllerAdvice
public class PstExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({ConstraintViolationException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraintViolation(
        ConstraintViolationException ex, WebRequest request) {

        ...

        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(...);
    }
}

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=7, message="Passport should have at least 7 characters")
    private String passportNumber;

    public Student() {
    }

...

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/addstudent"...)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Object> addStudent(@RequestBody StudentDto studentDto) {

    Student student = new Student();
    student.setId(studentDto.getId());                          // 1L
    student.setName(studentDto.getName());                      // "helen"
    student.setPassportNumber(studentDto.getPassportNumber());  // "321"

    studentRepository.save(student);

    return ResponseEntity.accepted().body(student);
}
```

thank you...

Comment: Could you try with HibernateException? just update this @ExceptionHandler({HibernateException.class}) and let me know what is your answer..?

Comment: thank you - though it didn't resolve issue. problem persists.

Comment: Oh right, I have taken a look and Exceptions like ConstraintViolationException are not taken in account because they are extend from HIbernateException as I thought. So PersistenceException instead of AnyException that extends from HibernateException is thrown. So I think you should update something like this: @ExceptionHandler({PersistenceException.class}) public ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraintViolation(PersistenceException ex, WebRequest request) { if (ex instanceof ConstraintViolationException)  { ConstraintViolationException consEx = (ConstraintViolationException) ex;

Comment: Let me know if this works..

Comment: I've researched right now and I've found an answer similar as I was commenting you but this answer is using spring framework.. you can take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052092/constraintviolationexception-in-spring-rest

Comment: I do receive a TransactionSystemException. ( I don't receive a PersistenceException). I think I have enough for a solution now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're 3 ways:

1. `@Valid` \ `@Validated` annotations.

   Once they used at parameter level, violations are available via method-injected `Errors` \ `BindingResult` type implementations.
2. `ConstraintViolationException` is thrown each time an entity in non-valid state is passed to `.save()` or `.persist()` Hibernate methods.
3. Entities may be manually validated via injected `LocalValidatorFactoryBean.validate()` method. The constraint violations then available through passed `Errors` object's implementation.
   Exactly, how `@Valid` \ `@Validated` annotations are internally implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions like ConstraintViolationException are not taken in account because they are extend from HibernateException. you can take a look [exceptions in convert method](https://github.com/emmanuelbernard/hibernate-core-ogm/blob/master/hibernate-entitymanager/src/main/java/org/hibernate/ejb/AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java#L1298) that those are wrapped on Hibernate Exceptions.

```
@ExceptionHandler({TransactionSystemException.class})
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraintViolation(TransactionSystemException ex, WebRequest request) {

    if (ex.getCause() instanceof RollbackException) {
       RollbackException rollbackException = (RollbackException) ex.getCause();
         if (rollbackException.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
             return new ResponseEntity<Object>(...);
         }
    ...
    }
    ...

    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot catch ConstraintViolationException.class because it's not propagated to that layer of your code, it's caught by the lower layers, wrapped and rethrown under another type. So that the exception that hits your web layer is not a ConstraintViolationException. So you could do something like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler({TransactionSystemException.class})
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handlePersistenceException(final Exception ex, final WebRequest request) {
    logger.info(ex.getClass().getName());
    //
    Throwable cause = ((TransactionSystemException) ex).getRootCause();
    if (cause instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {        

        ConstraintViolationException consEx= (ConstraintViolationException) cause;
        final List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (final ConstraintViolation<?> violation : consEx.getConstraintViolations()) {
            errors.add(violation.getPropertyPath() + ": " + violation.getMessage());
        }

        final ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, consEx.getLocalizedMessage(), errors);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(apiError, new HttpHeaders(), apiError.getStatus());
    }
    final ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), "error occurred");
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(apiError, new HttpHeaders(), apiError.getStatus());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue so I had to catch the `JDBCException` exception:

```
@ExceptionHandler({JDBCException.class})
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraintViolation(TransactionSystemException ex, WebRequest request) {

    if (ex.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
        ...
    }   

    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would help:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = {DataIntegrityViolationException.class})
public ResponseEntity<String> handlePreconditionFailed(DataIntegrityViolationException exception) {
        LOG.error(ERROR_MESSAGE, exception);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use the **@Valid** annotation in the Controller class but not in the Service class.

In my repository, I pass the method throw the service class and after passing it to the controller.

So if you pass method throw service you also have to pass **@Valid** annotation in the **Service class**